# How to update all or big part of JSON values in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have two json files - data.json and dataForUpdate.json

**data.json:**

```
 [{"name": "test",
   "isDefault": true,
   "settings": {
     "type": "Separation",
     "scanner": {
     "brightness": 0,
     "contrast": 0,
     "threshold": 0,
     "isDuplex": false,
      },
     "image": {
     "invertImage": false,
     "autoRotate": true,
     "rotateValue": -180
     }
    }
 }]
```

**dataForUpdate.json:**

```
  [{"name": "other",
   "isDefault": false,
   "settings": {
     "scanner": {
     "brightness": 100,
     "contrast": 50,
      },
     "image": {
     "autoRotate": false,
     "rotateValue": 0
     }
    }
 }]
```

I need to update first json with values from second. How can I do it without JSON.parse and hardcodded replacing.

Comment: loop through it

Comment: he can't loop over file contents without any parsing

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without use of any method, you can iterate over json and update matching keys and call recursively for objects.

```js
var data = {"name": "test",
   "isDefault": true,
   "settings": {
     "type": "Separation",
     "scanner": {
     "brightness": 0,
     "contrast": 0,
     "threshold": 0,
     "isDuplex": false,
      },
     "image": {
     "invertImage": false,
     "autoRotate": true,
     "rotateValue": -180
     }
    }
 }
 
var dataForUpdate = {"name": "other",
   "isDefault": false,
   "settings": {
     "scanner": {
     "brightness": 100,
     "contrast": 50,
      },
     "image": {
     "autoRotate": false,
     "rotateValue": 0
     }
    }
 }
 
 var update = function(a, b) {
  for(key in a) {
    if(b[key] !== undefined) {
      if(typeof b[key] === 'object') {
        update(a[key],b[key]);
      } else {
        a[key] = b[key];
      }
    }
  }
 }
 update(data, dataForUpdate);
 console.log(data);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)? You could do something like this:

```
var data = [{"name": "test",
   "isDefault": true,
   "settings": {
     "type": "Separation",
     "scanner": {
     "brightness": 0,
     "contrast": 0,
     "threshold": 0,
     "isDuplex": false,
      },
     "image": {
     "invertImage": false,
     "autoRotate": true,
     "rotateValue": -180
     }
    }
 }]

var dataForUpdate =   [{"name": "other",
   "isDefault": false,
   "settings": {
     "scanner": {
     "brightness": 100,
     "contrast": 50,
      },
     "image": {
     "autoRotate": false,
     "rotateValue": 0
     }
    }
 }]

Object.assign(data[0], dataForUpdate[0]);
```

**Browser compatibility**

- *Chrome* - 45+
- *Firefox* - 34+
- *Internet Explorer* - not supported
- *Edge* - all versions
- *Opera* - 32+
- *Safari* - 9+

Comment: Please add caveat about browser compatibility

Comment: I need to update only values, but not whole object.
This method will replace values but delete others.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, Then You can also use jQuery [extend](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/).

Like this

```js
var data = [{"name": "test",
   "isDefault": true,
   "settings": {
     "type": "Separation",
     "scanner": {
     "brightness": 0,
     "contrast": 0,
     "threshold": 0,
     "isDuplex": false,
      },
     "image": {
     "invertImage": false,
     "autoRotate": true,
     "rotateValue": -180
     }
    }
 }];
 var update = [{"name": "other",
   "isDefault": false,
   "settings": {
     "scanner": {
     "brightness": 100,
     "contrast": 50,
      },
     "image": {
     "autoRotate": false,
     "rotateValue": 0
     }
    }
 }];
 
 $.extend(data[0],update[0]);
 console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```